# Decomposition of any closed set as of countable union of compact sets

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading a book and it says any closed set $F$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be written as a countable union of compact sets as follows: $F=\cup_{k=1}^\infty F\cap B_k$ where $B_k$ are closed balls of radius $k$ centered at the origin.

> It probably seems obvious but I don't really understand why this would be true? I know that the sets in the union are compact because they are closed and bounded.

Comment: By distributive property: $$F = F \cap \Bbb R^n = F \cap (B_1 \cup B_2 \cup B_3 \cup \cdots ) = (F \cap B_1) \cup (F \cap B_2) \cup (F \cap B_3) \cup \cdots $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any point in the union is in some $F \cap B_k$, so in particular it is in $F$.  Thus $\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}(F \cap B_j) \subseteq F$.

On the other hand, given any point $x \in F$, let $k$ be a natural number larger than the distance from $x$ to the origin.  Then $x \in B_k$, so $x \in F \cap B_k$, so $x \in \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty (F \cap B_j)$.  So $F \subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}(F \cap B_j)$.

Answer (score 0):

$F\subset\mathbb R^n=\cup_{k=1}^\infty B_k$ and intersection is distributive over union:
$$F=F\cap\mathbb R^n=F\cap\left(\cup_{k=1}^\infty B_k\right)=\cup_{k=1}^\infty(F\cap B_k).$$

Comment: Sorry @Crostul I saw your comment only after editing my answer.